# Complete "Macroscopic" Measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $(X,\overline{\mathcal{M}},\overline{\mu})$ be it's completion. The definition of a complete measure can be interpreted as a complete "microscopic" measure, in the sense it can measure any subset of any null set in $\mathcal{M}$, which are the microscopic sets of $\mathcal{M}$. This has a intuitive appeal, makes all sense that this subsets has null measure, even if we can't measure them we would still think they "must" have null measure.

Following this idea, we can also think in a complete "macroscopic" measure, in the sense that any set containing a set in $\mathcal{M}$ with infinite measure is measurable and also have infinite measure. In other words, if $E\in\mathcal{M}$ and $\mu(E) =\infty$, then any $F\supset E$ is $\overline{\mathcal{M}}-$measurable, with $\overline{\mu}(F) = \infty$.

The idea is that I can think in "microscope" and "macroscopic" completion and try to compare them. Does anyone know (or can say) something about this approach?

Thank you.

Comment: Taking $\mathbb{R}$ and choosing any bounded non-measurable set, we can add it to a disjoint infinite-measure set and get a completion-measurable one. Detracting it back, we have that _all_ bounded sets are now measurable, which is too much to work with. So it should be some very exotic space for this procedure to be practical.

Comment: @Jorkug: I think you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @PhoemueX it could work with different classes of sets instead of sigma-algebras or in some other context, I just pointed out that it won't work with the standard integration theory. I myself would be interested to know if this concept is actually used somewhere.

Comment: I realized this few hours ago, too bad. I think it's interesting that we can assume all subsets of null sets can be also null sets, but can't do the same for infinite (infinite in measure) sets without compromising the theory.

Comment: Do you know what happens if you replace $\infty$ with $\mu(X)$ in your macroscopic definition, and $\mu$ happens to be a finite positive measure?

Comment: If the total measure is infinity I see no difference.